# Get datefield selected value from datagrid GridColumn

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

I have datefield in `DataGrid` `GridColumn` like following:

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Date" dataField="newDate" rendererIsEditable="true">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:GridItemRenderer>
               <mx:DateField id="dtNewDate" selectedDate="{new Date()}"/>
            </s:GridItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

Now want `dtNewDate` selectedValue then how can get that. If i get datafield value of gridColumn i.e. `newDate` but there is nothing.

So, how can i get new selected value of DateField?

**Edit:**

`dg.addEventListener(GridItemEditorEvent.GRID_ITEM_EDITOR_SESSION_SAVE, onSave)`;

```
private function onSave(event:GridItemEditorEvent):void
{
     // I want datefield value here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the new selected date, you can simply use the [`change`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#event:change) event on your `DateField` control :

```
<mx:DateField id="date" change="on_date_change(event)"/>
```

And

```
protected function on_date_change(e:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void
{
    var selected_date:Date = e.currentTarget.selectedDate;
    var date:String = selected_date.getFullYear().toString() 
        + '/' + (selected_date.getMonth()+1).toString() 
        + '/' + selected_date.getDate();

    trace(date);    // gives for example : 2015/12/31
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I don't want to value on change of dateField. If user does not change any value and keep selected value as it is then?

Comment: At the end not found any other solution will conclude with this solution.

Comment: @ketan You can set your default value into a var and set it when the date is changed to get at the final as the value that you need.